# CollectionChanged event on ObservableCollection doesn't listen to item update

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have an `ObservableCollection` of objects, where I update an individual object property on an OnClick event. I know that the `ObservableCollection` is a container, which means that it only notifies the bindingcontext of my view if an item is either added or removed.

Therefore I found a method to notify on a property update event.

```
public MenuViewModel()
{
    listOfItems = new ObservableCollection<MasterPageItem>(masterpageItems.getPages());
    listOfItems.CollectionChanged += items_CollectionChanged;
}
public void changeSelected(int index)
{
    if (index != -1)
    {
        listOfItems[index].isSelected = true;
    }
    int i = 0;
    foreach (MasterPageItem e in listOfItems)
    {
        if (i != index)
        {
            e.isSelected = false;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
static void items_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OldItems != null)
    {
        foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in e.OldItems)
            item.PropertyChanged -= item_PropertyChanged;
    }
    if (e.NewItems != null)
    {
        foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in e.NewItems)
            item.PropertyChanged += item_PropertyChanged;
    }
}

static void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

The above code, doesn't notify my view, when the isSelected property is changed. Therefore I'm kindly asking you, how I achieve to notify my view that the isSelected property is updated.

Comment: there should be no reason to do any of this if `MasterPageItem` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: Jason has right. Additionally I don't see any reason why you attach to each item PropertyChanged event, it should be done through xaml on ui control.

Comment: you are right, thank you!